# Почему Linux Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.1 (64-bit) , которая на Virtual Box cлегка притормаживает, работает не плавно?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

У меня Виндовс 10 (64-bit), на компьютере 16 гигабайт оперативаной памяти, встроенная видеопамять , ( у меня I6400 intel) 8 потоков

Почему Linux Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.1 (64-bit) , которая на Virtual Box cлегка притормаживает, работает не плавно ?

Под нее при установки выделил 2 ядра процессора ( у меня I6400 intel) , 4 гига оперативной памяти, 64 мегабайт оперативной памяти, включил 3d ускорение.
И вот при работе не всегда плавно передвигаются меню и могут быть подвизания. В диспетчере задач все ядра на половину загружены. Как можно настроить чтобы все плавно работало ? .Еще один нюанс. Виндовс у меня стоит на SSD диске, а виртуальную машину я сохранил на винчестере . У Вас на виртуальной машине Ubuntu работает также плавно, как и виндовс, или тоже заметно вялая работа операционной системы? Что я делаю не так, как исправить ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А видеодрайвера для этого самого 3d-ускорения в убунте установлены?

Comment: нет, не установлены , нужно было не ставить 3d-ускорение , тогда все плавно будет ?   Или найти драйвера для моей встройки для убунту и установить ?

Comment: Устройства → Подключить образ Дополнений гостевой ОС → открыть диск в убунте → запустить установщик в консоли от рута

Answer (score 0):

В твоем случае можно установить убунту на флешку или диск, запуститься с него и установить вместе с виндой, т.к объем ОЗУ и прочее позволяют тебе это сделать. У всех виртуалках будет лагать любая система, даже Линукс. А если ты не хочешь устанавливать убунту на комп, тогда просто можешь каждый раз запускаться с накопителя и выбирать режим  "Запустить без установки" или как-то так.

Comment: Нормально настроенные виртуалки имеют такую же (или почти такую же) производительность, как и сам компьютер; не надо вводить людей в заблуждение

Comment: @andreymal давай, расскажи как ты через VirtualBox играешь в The Witcher3 на полную мощь!

Comment: @zalex уже никак, потому что с момента написания комментария в VirtualBox 6.1 успели сломать всю графику к чертям :(

Comment: @andreymal, прости, не хотел показаться грубым, ответ конечно явно не точен, про то что "будет лагать любая система", однако очевидно если  речь идет о графике то еще терпим пока доминирование.

Comment: @zalex говорят, в более «взрослых» виртуалках (qemu и пр.) есть GPU Passthrough, который позволяет дать полную производительность графики (ценой монопольного захвата видеокарты), но лично не пробовал

Comment: @andreymal не вижу причины не поставить второй ОС для игр WIN, если уж хочется. Каждому свое, в конце концов :)